# How to fix main() at the end of the code?

Tags: python

```
def main()
    global FPSCLOCK, DISPLAYSURF, BASICFONT, RESET_SURF, NEW_SURF, NEW_RECT, SOLVE_SURF, SOLVE_RECT

    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = psygame.time.Clock()
    screen = psygame.display.set_mode(WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT)
    pygame.display.set_caption('puzzle')
    BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', BASICFONTSIZE)
```

end of code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

that is what my main() code looks like, but when i run my code (which plays a game, puzzle) the console says File "puzzle.py", line 330 in module>. What am I doing wrong?

Command Prompt(after i boot up game):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "puzzle.py", line 330, in <module>
    main()
  File "puzzle.py", line 46, in main
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT)
  TypeError: must be 2-item sequence, not int
```

Comment: Does it only say: "File "puzzle.py", line 330 in module>"? If not, please copy and pass all the error. By the way, are you using pygame? If yes, then you have misspelled it, it's `pygame.init()` not `pyfame.init()` or `psygame`.. I have not downvoted.

Comment: isn't `pyfame` a typo?

Comment: This is all it says. I just misspelled the pygame.

Comment: @DylanFendrich You still have a typo: `screen = psygame.display.set_caption('puzzle')`

Comment: Please include the entire traceback

Comment: I added the entire traceback

Comment: Is this `screen = psygame.display.set_mode(WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))` exactly what you have in your code? Node that you are missing a opening parenthesis (apart from the fact, as I said before, you are misspelling pygame again).

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Pygame's documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode), the method `set_mode` requires as first argument a tuple (and not an `int`).

I suppose your line

```
screen = psygame.display.set_mode(WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
```

should be

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
```

Comment: when i add the extra parenthesis, it adds another thing wrong in the command prompt and i misspelled it in the question, it is suppose to have one set of parenthesis in my code.

Comment: @DylanFendrich In this case, you probably need double parenthesis because the method `set_mode` accepts also a optional second and third parameter, so Python could be interpreting `WINDOWHEIGHT` as the second parameter and not as part of a tuple. Which error do you have if you add double parenthisis?

Comment: it now says: 

`C;\Python27\games\puzzle2.exe:52: RuntimeWArning: use font: DLL load failed
: The specified module could not be found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "puzzle2.py", line 330, in <module>
  File "puzzle2.py", line 46, in main
  File " pygame\__int__.pyc", line 70, in __getattr__
NotImplementedError: font module not available
(ImportError: DLL load Failed: The specified module could not be found.)`